# Exclude sub module of com.google.gms

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

Here is my `com.google.android.gms` module

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
|    |                   +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0
|    |                   |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |                   +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0
|    |                   |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |                   |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |                   +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0
|    |                   |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |                   |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |                   +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0
|    |                   |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |                   |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.2.0
|    |                        +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |                        +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |                        +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 (*)
|    |                        \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
```

Currently, I want to exclude `com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0` (because it have some bug with `Fragment`) so I do like

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

However, it not working. I find a clue in `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`. When I remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`, exclude work.

How can I exclude sub module of com.google.gms? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It think the problem is that you only exclude it in the transitive dependencies of that one single dependency.

Try to exclude it completely on all configurations like

```
configurations.all.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
```

Comment: It working but it also remove the `support-v4` in `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` (which I don't want). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Of course it does. Either you exclude the lib or not. You cannot exclude **and** include a lib. Except maybe by writing some custom classloaders.